# Does Spring Data's Pageable take a page number or a query offset?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-data

I'm using `spring-data jpa 1.1.0.M1` now we were using a much higher version and run into issues with `spring-data-mongodb` due to `spring-data-commons`. Because of that we've used entity manager in our service for certain query including queries with `offset` and `limit`.

Now that we've downgraded and everything seems to be fine we would like to maintain everything under repository level when it comes to `data access` and do much on Business Logic in the Services.

From this [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.1.2.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) i understand that `pageable interface` is what i need. But the implementation class [PageRequest](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.1.0.M1/api/) takes `page` argument. would that mean that my `offset` becomes the following?

```
offset = page* limit; => page = offset/limit;
```

Am I getting it right?
thanks for reading this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The PageRequest object has a constructor that takes the page and the size.  Other constructors allow you to specify additional detail such as the sort direction.

```
new PageRequest(int page, int size)
```

**See:** [Spring PageRequest API Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.0.0.M2/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html)

The `PageRequest` is passed as an argument to one of your repositories find methods.  In the following example I am getting the first five entries for my blog.

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String blog(Model model) {
    Sort sort = new Sort(Direction.DESC, "postId");
    model.addAttribute("posts",
            postViewRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(0, 5, sort))
                    .getContent());
    model.addAttribute("tease", true);
    return "blog/blog";
}
```

In this example the call to the repositories `findAll(PageRequest)` method returns a `org.springframework.data.domain.Page` object.  The `Page` object contains several convenient methods that allow information about the underlying ResultSet, such as size and number of pages, to be retrieved.

**See:** [Spring Page API Documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.0.0.M2/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Page.html)

Given these convenient features, I'm not sure you need to be concerned with managing the offset or the current page since Spring Data is performing this work for you.

Comment: You did not answer the question as to whether new PageRequest(0, 5, sort) implies offset zero results and return next 5 results or this is return page number 0 with 5 results.

Comment: If I want database items 2,4,5,6,7,8, what will be PageRequest? new PageRequest(2,5)?

Answer (score -1):

Spring uses page numbers that range from 1 - n.

To get the first five results use.

```
new PageRequest(1, 5);
```

To get the next five results use.

```
new PageRequest(2, 5);
```

The page index should not be confused with an offset of previous results.

Comment: wrong. https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.0.0.M2/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#PageRequest(int,%20int) **Pages are zero indexed, thus providing 0 for page will return the first page.**